# Symfony image upload

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I cant find why my code isn't working properly. I try to upload the image through the form and save it in a directory, but it isnt there. For a test I did echo on the file object from the form to display the name of the file and extension and its correct, but its not saving.

Here is my code:

Form:

```
class WgrajForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'zdjęcie' => new sfWidgetFormInputFile(),
      'nazwa'   => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
    ));

     $this->setValidators(array(
        'zdjęcie'    =>  new sfValidatorFile(array(
          'mime_types' => 'web_images',
          'path'       => '/projektSymfony/web/images',
        ),array(
          'mime_types' => 'Plik może być tylko zdjęciem'
        )
      ),
      'nazwa' => new sfValidatorString(array(), array('required' => 'pole wymagane')),
    ));

    $this->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('wgraj[%s]');
  }
}
```

Action:

```
public function executeDodaj(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->form= new WgrajForm();

  if ($request->isMethod('post'))
  {
    $this->form->bind(
    $request->getParameter('wgraj'),
    $request->getFiles('wgraj'));

    if ($this->form->isValid())
    {
      $wgrane       = $this->form->getValues();
      $plik         = $wgrane['zdjęcie'];
      $pliknazwa    = $wgrane['nazwa'];
      $rozszerzenie = $plik->getExtension($plik->getOriginalExtension());
      $plik->save('/projektSymfony/web/images/'.$pliknazwa.$rozszerzenie);
      //$this->redirect('galeria/index');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `path` parameter is better when you use `sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir')` or `sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir')` in your case.

You don't need to `save()` the widget inside your action. You just need to save the form, and then, it will save your image.

```
if ($this->form->isValid())
{
  $this->form->save();

  $this->redirect('galeria/index');
}
```

Take a look at the documentation, you will find lots of information, specially [the part of Jobeet tutorial about Form](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/10?orm=Doctrine).

Comment: it's a `sfForm` so it has not a save method